# Simple Binary Tree in Java in just one class

Tags: java

I have to implement a very simple binary tree. I just need a `put` and a `get` method. If a key is already in use i have to replace just the value. This is my code but i'm very very unsure if this is working right... can you confirm that this code will work? Sorry... i don't know how to debug such a class... :/ And no - it is not a homework. Just a template from a course to learn java... ;)

```
//Don't import any other classes.
public class BinaryTree<K extends Comparable<K>, V> {

    //Please don't add any further attributes.
    private K key;
    private V value;
    private BinaryTree<K, V> left;
    private BinaryTree<K, V> right;

    /**
     * This class is a binary tree-based collection for key-value-pairs.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      BinaryTree<Integer, String> treeInteger = new BinaryTree<>(2, "two ");
      treeInteger.put(1, "one ");
      treeInteger.put(0, "zero ");
      treeInteger.put(3, "three ");
      treeInteger.put(6, "six ");
      treeInteger.put(3, "threeNew ");


        System.out.println(tree.toString());

        if (tree.get(4) == null) {
            System.out.println("null");
        }
    }

    public BinaryTree(K key, V value) {
        //Fill in your solution here.
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void put(K key, V value) {
        //Fill in your solution here.
        if (this.key.compareTo(key) > 0 ) {
            // links
            if (this.left == null) {
                this.left = new BinaryTree<>(key, value);
            } else {
                left.put(key, value);
            }
        } else if (this.key.compareTo(key) < 0) {
            if (this.right == null) {
                this.right = new BinaryTree<>(key, value);
            } else {
                this.right.put(key, value);
            }
        } else if (this.key.compareTo(key) == 0) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    public V get(K key) {
        //Fill in your solution here.
        if (this.key.compareTo(key) > 0 && this.left != null) {
            return this.left.get(key);
        } else if (this.key.compareTo(key) < 0 && this.right != null) {
            return this.right.get(key);
        } else if (this.key.compareTo(key) == 0 && this.value != null) {
            return this.value;
        } else if (this.key == key) {
            return value;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

My own `touring`

```
    String s = "";

    if (left != null) {
        s += left.toString();
    }

    if (value != null) {
        s += value.toString();
    }

    if (right != null) {
        s += right.toString();
    }

    return s;
```

Comment: Why don't you run it?

Comment: Add some if-statements in the main method that ensure various points in the tree have the correct keys and values. SImple

Comment: @TungD.Nguyen because i don't know how to debug... Either my `toString` is not correct or my class..

Comment: I would suggest you start by learning how to use a unit testing tool such as JUnit. Then you can build some tests to verify if your code is working. That's a much better technique than print statements that you manually examine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this and test:

```
@Override
public String toString() {

    if(this.left==null&&this.right != null){
        return this.value.toString()+" " + this.right.toString();
    } 
    if(this.left!=null&&this.right == null){
        return this.value.toString()+" " + this.left.toString();
    } 

    if(this.left !=null && this.right != null)
    return this.value.toString()+" " + this.left.toString()
                +" " + this.right.toString();
    return this.value.toString();;
}
```

This is preorder [tree traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) that prints all nodes in the tree. If you create the tree correctly, it should be able to print all values.

To print in the ascending order, use in-order tree traversal:

```
@Override
public String toString() {

    if(this.left==null&&this.right != null){
        return this.value.toString()+" " + this.right.toString();
    } 
    if(this.left!=null&&this.right == null){
        return  this.left.toString() +" " + this.value.toString();
    } 

    if(this.left !=null && this.right != null)
    return this.left.toString()
                +" " +this.value.toString()+" "  + this.right.toString();
    return this.value.toString();
}
```

Comment: The result is: one two threeNew seven six five NineNine. :)

Comment: Thanks.. i changed my main method. Startet with a 2 and added after that a 0. Now the output is wrong.. do u know why? I can't find a mistake

Comment: "two zero threeNew seven six five NineNine" is correct: for preorder. Nothing is wrong

Comment: Thanks! I just added my own toString for the final output. Seems to be ok. :)